# sets in Z3 theorem prover

Tags: java, z3, alloy

I have a declaration in Alloy

```
sig Card{}
sig ATM {card :  disj  set Card}
```

and I converted it into Z3 like that:

```
1- (declare-sort ATM) 
2- (declare-fun isATM (ATM) Bool)
3- (declare-sort Card)
4- (declare-fun isCard (Card) Bool)
5- (declare-fun card (ATM Card) Bool)
6- (assert(forall ((c Card) (atm ATM)) (=> (card atm c) (and(isATM atm) (isCard c))))) 
7- (declare-fun disjSetCard (ATM) Card)
8- (assert(forall ((atm ATM) (c Card))  (=> (card atm c)(= c(disjSetCard atm)))))
check sat
```

The question is, in line 7, how to make the function `disjSetCard` return `(disj set)` of Cards instead of one Card. Is my code correct or is there a different solution, please?

Comment: what do you mean by what ??

Comment: I mean How to declare one to many in Z3 ?

Comment: Was the provided answer helpful and/or useful to you? If not, it would be useful to hear why not, as well as any feedback in general. If yes, can you [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the relation with a function that returns a set:

```
(define-sort Set (T) (Array T Bool))    
(declare-sort ATM)     
(declare-sort Card)    
(declare-fun ATMtoCard (ATM) (Set Card))
```

And constrain the field values of distinct members of ATM to be disjoint, with:

```
(forall ((a Card) (x ATM) (y ATM))
(=>
  (and (select (ATMtoCard x) a) (select (ATMtoCard y) a))
  (= x y)
))
```

Which corresponds to Alloy expression:

```
all a: Card | all x, y: ATM |
a in x.card && a in y.card implies x = y
```